# Debug symbols not created when using cmake

Tags: c++, gdb, cmake

I compiled the c++ code library at [github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o](http://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) using cmake after adding

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

so as to be able to debug the application. Then it created a build file named "g2o". But when I try debugging with gdb, this is the output I get.

```
user2@arm_machine:~/g2o/trunk/bin$ gdb g2o
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /scratch/mbaxkms7/ARM_Programs_mbaxkms7/g2o/trunk/bin/g2o...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb)
```

Is there any other way to generate debug information while using cmake?

Comment: What kind of target is g2o? Is it an executable, a static library or a shared library? What does your project CMakeLists.txt look like?

Comment: it is an executable..i am compiling the code library at https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o

Comment: It's probably a problem within the project. If it is your code, provide a minimum example that shows the problem. If it not your code, contact the owner about the bug.

Comment: What is the command you use to build this project? Perhaps you should add a `MESSAGE( STATUS "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" )` to see if your build flag is properly parsed.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach with adding `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` works fine.

But `g2o` is the program which was build with `Release` options. `Debug` version of `g2o` is called `g2o_d`. Thus to debug you need launch debugger in the following way:

```
user2@arm_machine:~/g2o/trunk/bin$ gdb g2o_d
```

**Note**
Different names isn't common feature of `CMake` but only of the `g2o` [project](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L19):

```
# postfix, based on type
SET(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d" CACHE STRING "postfix applied to debug build of libraries")
SET(CMAKE_RELEASE_POSTFIX "" CACHE STRING "postfix applied to release build of libraries")
```